# Finding Records 90 Days or Less in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have this code and I would like to take the given date values create a separate column calculating days between and only want the records 90 days or less from today. The column consist of over 25K rows all being in datetime format. I would like to create a new column that looks at todays date and iterates through the dates column to get the amount of days in-between.  Below is an example:

```
id     date        
 1     2022-3-17
 2     2021-12-12
 3     2023-1-13
```

And I would like to be able to use todays date to get in a new column the days between

```
id      date          days
 1      2022-3-17     347
 2      2021-12-12    442
 3      2023-1-13     45
```

Every time I try and change todays date to datetime it changes it to a time stamp.

```
 today = date.today()
 today = pd.to_datetime(today)
```

Comment: What is the output of `df['date'].dtype`?

Comment: dtype('<M8[ns]')

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df['days'] = (pd.Timestamp.today() - df['date']).dt.days
df90 = df[df['days'] <= 90]
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   id       date  days
0   1 2022-03-17   347
1   2 2021-12-12   442
2   3 2023-01-13    45

>>> df90
   id       date  days
2   3 2023-01-13    45
```

Answer (score 0):

You might create timedelta by comparing today with your dates and then select only those lesser than timedelta(days=90) following way

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"date":[datetime.date(2022,3,17),datetime.date(2021,12,12),datetime.date(2023,1,3)]})
df['lessor90d'] = (datetime.date.today() - df["date"]) <= datetime.timedelta(days=90)
print(df)
```

gives output

```
         date  lessor90d
0  2022-03-17      False
1  2021-12-12      False
2  2023-01-03       True
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost on the right way. You can use:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

dates = [
    datetime.date(2022, 3, 17), 
    datetime.date(2021, 12, 12), 
    datetime.date(2023, 1, 13)
]
df = pd.DataFrame(dates, columns=["date"])
df["diff"] = (datetime.date.today() - df["date"]).dt.days
print(df)
```

which outputs

```
         date  diff
0  2022-03-17   347
1  2021-12-12   442
2  2023-01-13    45
```

You can then filter the rows that have a difference in days of 90 or less with a simple filter:

```
df = df[df["diff"] <= 90]
```

Comment: Now what if I have a column called date with 25k values to it?

Comment: the same.. pandas is made exactly for that, vectorized operations